# Make a pattern in lua that match one parenthese and string

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want to make a pattern that matches strings like `(figure`.

I tried

```
string.find("See this example (figure 1), "%(%figure$")
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` if it isn't string finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `%(%figure$` pattern is invalid, it throws

```
missing '[' after '%f' in pattern
```

because `%f` defines a *[frontier pattern](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FrontierPattern)*.

You may use

```
string.match("See this example (figure 1)", "%((figure%s*%d+)%)")
```

See [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/dZbUx2)

**Details**

- `%(` - a `(` char
- `(figure%s*%d+)` - Capturing group (this value will be the output of `string.match`): `figure`, zero or more whitespaces (`%s*`) and then 1+ digits (`%d+`)
- `%)` - a `)` char

Comment: @DamienDotta BTW, FYI: If you need to extract just the digits, move the open capturing parenthesis before `%d`: `%(figure%s*(%d+)%)`

Comment: ok and if I just need to extract `(figure` without withespace and the digits ?

Comment: @DamienDotta Same way, adjust the position of the capturing parentheses, `(%(figure)%s*%d+%`. Or, if you want to match `(figure`,  use `%(figure`. Since `(` and `)` are used to define capturing groups in patterns, you need to prepend them with `%` to make them literal characters.